# Keyboard buffer and CPU

Tags: keyboard, duplex

Are modern computers use full-duplex or half-duplex communication between keyboard buffer and CPU or its mixed? If we are entering some commands in terminal i suppose that that is half-duplex because that command is executed after hitting enter, where is full-duplex used?

Comment: Huh? Keyboards are interrupt driven. Nothing to do with duplex.

Comment: [Keyboard controller (computing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_controller_(computing))

Comment: @DavidPostill I agree. I and another person have submitted an answer to try and explain the difference. Feedback/edits/negative agreements are appreciated lol.

Comment: @DrZoo The answers are fine. I voted to close as unclear, as I've no idea what the user is really wanting to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On "modern" computers, you can connect the keyboard via USB or via the PS/2 keyboard port. Both use a half-duplex protocol (data can be sent only one direction at a time, not both directions at once). That's not particularly important, though, because the only data that's *sent* to the keyboard consists of turning the LEDs on and off. So most data goes from the keyboard to the computer, all the time. Also, a human cannot press keys fast enough to saturate the line.

> If we are entering some commands in terminal i suppose that that is half-duplex because that command is executed after hitting enter, where is full-duplex used?

That has nothing to do with "full-duplex" or "half-duplex", possibly you misunderstood the meaning of the words.

Comment: Thank you for answer, and yes I misunderstood, anyway I quess you understood what I am trying to say and gave me good answer.

Comment: I do not believe the keyboard lights have data that is sent back to the keyboard. That is data that is handled locally by the keyboard hardware, by simply flipping logic gates open or closed to allow or cut the power from illuminating the light. The CPU does not send a signal saying "turn your light off."

Comment: @DrZoo: For PS/2, see [here](http://www.computer-engineering.org/ps2keyboard/). The command to set LEDs is `0xED`. For USB, see [here](http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/HID1_11.pdf). There are example HID output descriptors to set the keyboard LEDs, and see Appendix C says explicitely: "Synchronization between LED states and CAPS LOCK, NUM LOCK, SCROLL LOCK, COMPOSE, and KANA events is maintained by the host and NOT the keyboard".

Comment: @dirkt the USB page was dense lol. I found it in the PS/2 one though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would say modern PC's make it hard to depict keyboard as duplex hardware. The differences between half-duplex and full-duplex is the ability to send and receive data at the same time. With a keyboard, the keyboard sends keys to the buffer to be consumed by the CPU one by one.

Now days, a CPU interrupt is used to check for key presses. This happens multiple times per second. The generated interrupt then records the key presses into the keyboard buffer for the CPU to consume and use it accordingly.

That being said, the CPU never puts data into a queue to be sent to the keyboard.

Based on this wiki article on [keyboard buffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_buffer), the only way I can semi-understand a half-duplex keyboard is on old school terminals. Even on the old school systems, I would see it more as a half-duplex system, rather than a half-duplex keyboard.

Comment: A terminal was very bad example of what I am trying to say, I was just thinking about general protocols of communication between keyboard and CPU.

Comment: @Newbie Did you read the wiki article? "In half-duplex systems, keystrokes are echoed locally on a computer terminal. The user can see the command line on his terminal and edit it before it is transmitted to the main computer. Thus the buffer is local." As I explained in my answer, half-duplex is you either send **OR** receive data. Full-duplex allows the sending **AND** receiving data at the same time. On a terminal you either type a command **OR** execute a command. You can't type a new command while one is executing. Thus, half-duplex.